# Dynamically change font color based on contrast

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm looking to change the font color based on the color/contrast of what is behind it. i.e. if the color behind the text is white/light, the text will be black, if the color is dark/black, the font color will be white. Is this something that is achievable with mapbox? Or should I just go the route of outlining the text or something else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mechanism I can think of that would let you achieve such a thing. The normal solution is to use `text-halo-color` to set an outline colour, so the label's colour is readable against any background.